# How to create dynamic parameters in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to create a Jenkins job that copies some file from one server to another. I have a list of servers. What I want is to define two parameters SOURCE and TARGET, and use Groovy scripts to create a dropdown list for each parameter, like for SOURCE, the list looks like this:

```
return [
  "server1",
  "server2",
  "server3",
  "server4",
  "server5"
]
```

For the second parameter, I want the list be the same as above, but remove the one that was chosen in the first parameter. So if server1 was chosen for SOURCE, the list for TARGET should be:

```
return [
  "server2",
  "server3",
  "server4",
  "server5"
]
```

If server3 was chosen for SOURCE, then the list for TARGET will be:

```
return [
  "server1",
  "server2",
  "server4",
  "server5"
]
```

I can use Groovy for the TARGET like:

```
if (SOURCE.equals("server1")) {
return [ "server2","server3","server4","server5" ]
}
else if (SOURCE.equals("server2")) {
....
```

But the list is over 50 long and I prefer not to have over 50 "if"s in the script.

Is there a better way to create the TARGET list = the SOURCE list - the SOURCE choice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the below.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        script{
            // Get input 1 here
            def firstList = getListEnv()
            echo "First List : $firstList"
            
            // User selected server4
            def selectedServer = "server4"
            
            // Get the second List now
            def nl = excludeAndGet(selectedServer)
            echo "Second List : $nl"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def excludeAndGet(name) {
    def list =  getListEnv()
    list.remove(list.indexOf(name))
    return list
}

def getListEnv(){
    return [
  "server1",
  "server2",
  "server3",
  "server4",
  "server5"
]
}
```